# Is it possible to use multiple captcha based on language selection?

Tags: 7, captcha, advertising

I have a multi-language site.I wish to integrate captcha based on which language is selected.

```
Suppose if i selected language1 then captcha1
language1 => captcha1
language2 => captcha2
```

Comment: what is the difference between the two captchas?

Comment: Suppose i am using third party "Mollom" and need to setup other one too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should do this in `template.php`. First check the language then add the captcha based on the language. As an example to do this in webforms:

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    global $language;
    if($language->name == "ENGLISH")
    { 
        if (strstr($form_id, 'webform_client_form')) {
            $form['my_captcha_element'] = array(
                '#type' => 'captcha',
                '#captcha_type' => 'image_captcha/Image',
            );
        }
     }
}
```

You can check the language and add the `mollom` programmatically as well. Follow this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/717874) to learn how to add mollom by code.